# How to use Alfresco.component.getDNDUploadInstance() in Alfresco Share 4.2

Tags: drag-and-drop, yui, alfresco

I see [this](http://sharextras.org/jsdoc/share/community-4.0.d/symbols/Alfresco.DNDUpload.html) in the examples for using a pretty html5 file upload in client-side javascript of Share of the Alfresco Community version.
I try to use it as per instructions:

```
this.widgets.myWidget = Alfresco.component.getDNDUploadInstance();
```

Unfortunately, I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getDNDUploadInstance'
```

What am I missing here? Do I need some dependencies? I included alfresco.js, alfresco-dnd.js to my Share dashlet.

Comment: ?? Your question isn't clear. 1. What do you plan to do exactly 2. Where in Alfresco are you doing it (e.g. custom page/customization of an existing page --> name it) 3. present clearer code. Your oneliner isn't clear, I don't know where this.widgets comes from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code snippet included in the class JSDoc may be out of date.

Since the class `Alfresco.DNDUpload` seems to implement the capabilities, you should be able to use something like

```
dndUpload = new Alfresco.DNDUpload(elid);
var multiUploadConfig =
{
   destination: destination,
   siteId: siteId,
   containerId: doclibContainerId,
   path: docLibUploadPath,
   filter: [],
   mode: dndUpload.MODE_MULTI_UPLOAD,
}
dndUpload.show(multiUploadConfig);
```

Your `elid` should contain the ID of the Dom element that you are going to render the upload component into - you may find that you need to predefine some markup within there. The expression `args.htmlid` is normally used to supply the value in your web script.

You should also check out the parameters supported by the `show()` method ([docs](http://sharextras.org/jsdoc/share/community-4.0.d/symbols/Alfresco.DNDUpload.html#show)). I could not see a `files` parameter listed so I removed this, but you should review the other values you supply in order to ensure you are specifying appropriate values.

If you need further reference material then check out the `dnd-upload.get` web script ([source dir](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/slingshot/config/alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/upload/)).

Comment: This kind of helps. I'm having a bit of trouble with the elid, was trying to set it as a string literal, as a YUI Element, but the method show() keeps telling me there is no innerHTML of null. Gotta go see what's missing there, thanks anyway.

Comment: Yeah, you need to use the Freemarker expression `${args.htmlid}-blah` to set the `elid` (the `-blah` bit can be whatever unique suffix you like), and you need to set it in the JS code as well as the `id` attribute of the HTML element (probably a `<div>`) where you want your uploader to be rendered.

Comment: Thanks Will, but it didn't help. Like I said, I tried to set the element id as YUI element and as string literal (basically this.id + "-my-element"), but no help. I'll dig further and post a better question next time.